# Add an additional 1 way switch

Tags: lighting

We live a New build property our outside lights are pir and are a bit rubbish so the plan is to swap them out for non pir controlled by a switch we want to add in the kitchen Which is the other side of the wall to the FSU in the pic

The pic is the current set up I see in the under stairs cupboard. I added the single socket purely to charge the Dyson we have.
My concern is if I come off the wiring inside the FSU I am going to turn the single socket off as well as the outside lights from the switch in the kitchen.

Helpful advice needed :-)

[image]

Comment: Where you located? What is an FSU ? We would need to know what wires are available where you want the switch. Welcome to Stack Exchange DIY but a little more info is needed to be helpful

Comment: Also what is pir?

Comment: Lol I’m really glad I posted now

Comment: By the way I’m not an electrician

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you (e.g. is "PIR" "passive infra-red motion sensor"?). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: This is the strangest forum I’ve been part of, why do u lot need to know where I am? Surely any electrically sound person knows what I meant by fsu or fcu or fused switch, I seem to have walked into a barrage of sarcasm, I’ll expect you lot to know the terminology of my profession. I won’t be taking the tour thanks this ain’t my 1st rodeo. And seriously am I being asked to confirm what a pir for a light is......I am obviously posted in the wrong place. So long.